# Showing $|K : H \cap K| \le |G:H|$ where $H,K \le G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I'd appreciate input on the validity or lack thereof of my attempted proof of the following:

> Let $H,K \le G$ be subgroups, where $|G:H| < \infty$.
>
> a) Show that $|K:H \cap K| \le |G:H|$.
>
> b) Show that equality occurs in (a) if and only if $HK=G$.

a) Let $S$ be the set of left cosets of $H \cap K$ in $K$ and $R$ the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$.  Let $\phi:S \to R$ be given by $\phi(k(H \cap K))=kH$.  First we'll prove that this map is well defined: suppose $k_1(H \cap K)=k_2(H \cap K)$.  Then $k_2^{-1}k_1(H \cap K)=H \cap K$ so that $k_2^{-1}k_1 \in H \cap K$ and in particular $k_2^{-1}k_1 \in H$.  Then we have $k_2^{-1}k_1H=H$ and $k_1H=k_2H$, so $\phi(k_1(H \cap K))=\phi(k_2(H \cap K))$ and $\phi$ is well defined.

Next we'll show injectivity.  Let $k_1(H \cap K), k_2(H \cap K) \in S$ and suppose $\phi(k_1(H \cap K))=\phi(k_2(H \cap K))$, or $k_1H=k_2H$, so $k_2^{-1}k_1H=H$ and $k_2^{-1}k_1 \in H$.  Since $k_1,k_2 \in K$ we then have $k_2^{-1}k_1 \in H \cap K$ so $k_2^{-1}k_1(H \cap K)=H \cap K$ and $k_1(H \cap K)=k_2(H \cap K)$, so $\phi$ is injective.  It follows that $|K:H \cap K| \le |G:H|$.

b) Suppose $HK=G=KH$ ($HK$ is a subgroup iff $HK=KH$) and let $\phi$ be as above.  Let $gH=khH \in R$.  Since $h \in H$, $khH=kH$.  Then $\phi(k(H \cap K))=kH$, so $\phi$ is surjective and $|K:H \cap K|=|G:H|$.

Now suppose that $|K:H \cap K|=|G:H|$ and let $R_R$ be the set of right cosets of $H$ and $S_R$ be the set of right cosets of $H \cap K$.  Then for each coset $Hg \in R_R$ there is a coset $(H \cap K)k \in S_R$.  Therefore we can form the cosets $Hk$ for each $(H \cap K)k \in S_R$.  It follows that $G=\displaystyle\bigcup_{k \in K} Hk$, so $G=HK$.

Are these proofs correct?  Thanks.

Comment: The second part of the answer of b) is not very clear, why you don't try to see that $\phi$ is surjective in that case.  The remainder is perfectly correct, felicitation.

Comment: @Yassine: We know that there's a bijective (therefore surjective) map from $R_R$ to $S_R$ because $|K:H \cap K|=|G:H|$.

Comment: Yes, but you need to work with a specific one.  You can either work direcltly with the already defined injective (so it is surjective) mapping $\phi$ between the corresponding left cosets, or you may define more clearly its analogue for the right cosets.

Comment: @Yassine: I understand, thanks.